# Get item from item template frame in RadRotator

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radrotator

I have a Rad-rotator and a method _itemClicked in which I can found out the index of the clicked item. Actually for test purpose it is shown in label1.:

```
protected void RadRotator1_ItemClick(object sender, RadRotatorEventArgs e)
    {
       Telerik.Web.UI.RadRotatorItem frame = e.Item;
           int index = frame.Index;

           Label1.Text = index.ToString();
    }
```

Now I need to get one of the templateItem in the clicked frame and I am battling to find a method to access it. So far this I tried in several ways to access the frame by index but I am not getting anywhere.

how can I access the frame index to get a specific item value?

```
var frameContent= frame.Index[index]..... //this is not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access the controls by index inside the [RadRotatorItem](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/properties_t_telerik_web_ui_radrotatoritem.html) through the Controls property like this:

```
var frameContent = frame.Controls[i];
```

The property Controls contains a Collection of elements that inherit from the Control Super Type such as Label, Image, Literal, etc. you can also find a control by its Id for example find a Image (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image) with ID="Image1":

```
var frameImage = frame.findContol("Image1");
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have not solved the problem but it is useful. If you can help me further, I need to get the value of an hidden field inside the rotator and I am not getting it. This is the field which is one of the items: <asp:HiddenField ID="rssLink" runat="server" Value='<%= System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(XPath("link").ToString()%>' />

Comment: Try to get the value like this:
`System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField hiddenField = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField)frame.FindControl("rssLink");
    Label1.Text = hiddenField.Value;`